# How can I stop unknown people on Facebook from poking or sending Friend requests to me?

Tags: facebook

There does not seem to be any way in the current Facebook settings for stopping unknown people from poking me or reducing the "Can send friend request" list to narrower than "Friends of Friends". Any suggestions how to achieve this?

Comment: I doubt you can go below "Friends of Friends" for either of them, even with scripts. It might be possible not to show them on the home page via some custom scripts, but then you would miss also some legitimate requests.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure the second part of the question question makes sense...

If you think of Facebook connections as ever-widening circles, you have:

- Yourself

  - Friends

    - Friends of Friends

      - Strangers

You want to reduce the "can send friends request" to "narrower than 'Friends of Friends'", right? But if you look at the hierarchy above, exactly who would include? Either "some" Friends of Friends, which Facebook would need to know how to narrow to "some", or just to "Friends". If the latter, well, Friends don't need to send you a friends request, true?

Comment: You are right ...actually my intent was simply to block friend requests altogether. The reason for the question being put in this way was because "Can send friend requests" is the way Facebook presents that option ... not as a simple option to block friend requests.